# How to pass a id value to my modal in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

I have a display page that displays the data in a particular table. I'm displaying the data in a table, since i'm not displaying all the fields in the table I want to display a detailed version of that field in a pop-up box called modal in bootstrap twitter.

The snapshots of the display page are given below.

[image: Display page mentioned before]

[image: Popup that comes from clicking on a button]

To display the values in this pop-up I have to be able to access the id value inside the pop-up. 
My code for my page is given below.

```
<%@page import="Product.Op_Product"%>
<%@page import="Common.general"%>
<%@page import="Category.Op_Category" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<jsp:include page="Headj.jsp"/>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function deletedata(scatid) {
            var url = "Con_Category?action=deletescat&scatid=" + scatid;
            window.location = url;
        }
    </script>
    <div id="maindiv" class="container-fluid">
        <jsp:include page="Headerj.jsp"/>
        <div id="menu_content">
            <jsp:include page="Menuj.jsp"/>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                <h1 class="page-header">Product</h1>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Display</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Insertprd.jsp?pg=prd">Add New</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#">Messages<a><li>-->
                </ul>
                <br><br>
                <div class="alert-success"><p>${param.message}</p></div>
                        <%
                            general gen = new general();
                            Op_Product opp = new Op_Product();
                            Op_Category opc = new Op_Category();
                            ResultSet rs = opp.getallproducts();
                        %>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <th><strong>Sl. No.</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Unique ID</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Product</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Category</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Sub-Category</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Creator</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Operations</strong></th>
                    </thead>
                    <%
                        int no = 1;
                        while (rs.next()) {
                    %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= no%></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("prdf1")%></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("prdf2")%></td>
                        <td><%= opc.getOnecategoryname(rs.getString("prdf3"))%></td>
                        <td><%= opc.getOnesubcategoryname(rs.getString("prdf4"))%></td>
                        <td><%= gen.getCreator(rs.getString("prdf9"))%></td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="deletedata('<%= rs.getString("prdf1")%>');">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="editdata('<%= rs.getString("prdf1")%>')">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                            </button>//button to click to display pop-up
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <%
                            no++;
                        }
                    %>
                </table>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <jsp:include page="Footerj.jsp"/>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    **<!-- Display values here-->**
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me how to to display the value in the pop-up. I have done this in php symfony using  tag inside the modal.

Comment: you can load the content corresponding to id using AJAX, Did you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `e.relatedTarget` to find out who invoked the modal.  Then use that information during the `show.bs.modal` event however you want:

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').html('Fired By: ' + e.relatedTarget.id);
})
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/THBm7/)

See also: [How to get Twitter Bootstrap Modal's invoker element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21304908/1366033)