# How can you pull a PHP value from a table row in JQuery to use later?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Button that gets populated with ever row in the table.  I want to be able to put the value of the row "$row[auditID]" and use it in my modal to be able to make this delete button work.  The alert pops up, but the Modal won't hide and my delete action doesn't work (doesn't delete the audit).

```
<a href=\"#\" id=\"$row[auditID]\" class='btn btn-danger  btn-xs' role='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#question_alert' Title=\"Remove\" >Remove</span>   </a>";

<!-- modal pop up for Deleting a audit -->
<div class="modal fade" style="z-index:10000" id="question_alert" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Audit Delete Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"id="myModal1">
                <h3>Are you sure you want to <strong>DELETE</strong> this Audit? You will not be able to get it back.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <form method = "POST">
                <input type="button" id="yes_delete" value="Yes " name="deleteaudit" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery Script:

```
<script> 
 $("#yes_delete").click(function(){
var auditID = this.id;
//alert("delete test");
    $.post("edit_audits.php?action=delete&auditID="+auditID,{
    function(data){
        alert("Audit Deleted");
        $('question_alert').modal('hide');
        window.location.reload();
        }
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: `this` in the click handler will be the `<input type="button" id="yes_delete">` element, not the `<a>` that opened the modal in the first place, so `auditID` will be `"yes_delete"` which of course won't work.

Comment: Is there anything I can add or do as a remedy?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21304908/1385572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

Put your PHP value into the a tag like this:

```
    <a href="#" data-mylink="<?php echo $yourPHPVar; ?>" class='btn btn-danger  btn-xs' role='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#question_alert' Title="Remove" ><span>Remove</span> </a>
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lx6L4d9/)</kbd>

```js
$('#question_alert').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
 var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
 var linked = btn.data('mylink');
 $('#audNo').text(linked);
// Or:
// var modal = $(this);
// modal.find('.modal-body h3 span#audNo').text(linked);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="bob" data-mylink="Fred" class='btn btn-danger  btn-xs' role='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#question_alert' Title="Remove" ><span>Remove</span> </a>

<!-- modal pop up for Deleting a audit -->
<div class="modal fade" style="z-index:10000" id="question_alert" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Audit Delete Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"id="myModal1">
                <h3>Are you sure you want to <strong>DELETE</strong> Audit number <span id="audNo"></span>? You will not be able to get it back.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <form method = "POST">
                <input type="button" id="yes_delete" value="Yes " name="deleteaudit" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove' data-id="<?=$row["auditID"]?>" role='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#question_alert' Title="Remove" >Remove</span></a>

<!-- modal pop up for Deleting a audit -->
<div class="modal fade" style="z-index:10000" id="question_alert" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Audit Delete Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"id="myModal1">
                <h3>Are you sure you want to <strong>DELETE</strong> this Audit? You will not be able to get it back.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <form method = "POST">
                <input type="button" id="yes_delete" value="Yes " name="deleteaudit" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And This in The jQuery function. Make sure you put your jQuery script tag at the top of the page for jQuery to load before this function

```
<script>
var removeId = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-remove").click(function(){
        removeId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    });
    $("#yes_delete").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "edit_audits.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=delete&auditID="+removeId,
            success: function(){
                $('#question_alert').modal('hide');
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Keep in mind, I have not ran this as I don't have all the data needed. You may have to debug this a little as it was blind coding.

Comment: I thought that classes would conflict with bootstrap... (.btn-remove).  If they don't that is great!  I appreciate your answer. Thanks.