# How to pass value from forloop to url on modal with Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I have a forloop with buttons and their respective pk values.

```
{% for obj in all_objects %}
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ obj.pk }}" data-target="#myModal" class="open-my-modal"> {{ obj }} </button>
{% endfor %}
```

In **myModal** I have an url with pk=0 to be dynamically changed when an object is selected.

```
<a id="doSomething" href="{% url 'myapp:do_something' pk=0 %}">Do something</a>
```

I tried the following but I am getting the error Reverse for 'do_something' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found.

```
{% block jquery %}
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".open-my-modal", function () {
      // get the obj pk
      var objPk = $(this).data('id');  // this properly returns the pk value
      // pass obj pk to the django path variable 'pk'
      document.getElementById("doSomething").setAttribute("href", "{% url 'myapp:do_something' pk=objPk %}");
</script>
{% endblock jquery %}
```

How do I dynamically set the django path variable (pk) inside the href to the selected obj.pk value?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21304908/1637351, get the triggering element then use `.data('id')`.

Comment: @ schillingt I read that and still couldn't solve this issue. My problem is not passing the value to the modal but passing to the django url path variable

Answer (score 0):

Try approaching your problem from a different angle. Rather than attempting to generate the href in javascript, take advantage of django's templates and simply replace the href with a data attribute.

```
{% for obj in all_objects %}
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ obj.pk }}" data-target="#myModal" data-do-something-url="{% url 'myapp:do_something' pk=obj.pk %}" class="open-my-modal"> {{ obj }} </button>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in JS

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".open-my-modal", function (e) {
      var trigger = $(e.relatedTarget)
      document.getElementById("doSomething").setAttribute("href", trigger.data('do-something-url')
</script>
```

Comment: You can figure out which attribute to use on `e` with a debugger.